# Advise with choosing a linear algebra library for C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

Please, help me with choosing a library for C++ that can provide with **high performance** calculations in linear algebra.

Can you please share your experience with **Armadillo** library (http://arma.sourceforge.net/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd choose between [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or Sonys vectormath library ( google for vectormath aos , can't seem to find a direct download but it's a part of bullet ). Sonys library has less bells & whistles, a tad more inconvenient syntax, but it's fast, especially for their own platforms. Sonys library is limited to the subset of linear algebra used for games however, matrices doesn't go beyond 4x4 for example.

Comment: Thank you! I will give Eigen a try.